# Iterating through dataframe and updating based on dictionary conditions

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I have the following xlsx file that I need to work on: [image]

I want to iterate through the dataframe and if the column ITEM CODE contains a dictionary key, I want to check on the same row if contains a dictionary value[0] (first position in the tuple) and if contains I want to insert dictionary value[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AmJX.png) (second position in the tuple) into another column named SKU

Dataframe: #df3 = df2.append(df1)
[image]

```
catp = {"2755":(('24','002'),('25','003'),('26','003'),('27','004'),('28','005'),('29','006'),('30','007'),('31','008'),
                ('32','009'),('32','010'),('33','011'),('34','012'),('35','013'),('36','014')),
        "2513":(('38','002'),('40','003'),('42','004'),('44','005'),('46','006'),('48','007'),('50','008'),('52','009'),
               ('54','010'))}

for i, row in df3.iterrows():
    if catp.key() in df3['ITEM CODE'][i] and catp.value()[0] in df3['TG'][i]:
            codmarime = catp.value()[1]
            df3['SKU'][i] = '20'+df3['ITEM CODE'][i]+[i]+codmarime

    else:
        df3['SKU'][i] = '20'+df3['ITEM CODE'][i]+'???'
```

If 2755 and 24 found SKU = '202755638002'

If 2513 and 44 found SKU = '202513123005'

Output xlsx
[image]

Comment: Also provide sample dataframe

Comment: Is that ok? https://imgur.com/enrKxa6 , inserted also into post

Comment: You provided a **picture**. Please provide the **text** content.

Comment: Your code contains `codmarime = ''` at the end of both *if* and *else* variants. What is the purpose of these substitutions?

Comment: Edited and removed codmarime = ' ' . It was for testing at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you failed to provide text data to create at least a fragment of your DataFrame,
I copied from your picture 3 rows, creating my test DataFrame:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [ '1513452', 'AVRO D2', '685', 'BLACK/BLACK/ANTRACITE', '24', 929.95, '8052644627565' ],
    [ '2513452', 'AVRO D2', '685', 'BLACK/BLACK/ANTRACITE', '21', 929.95, '8052644627565' ],
    [ '2755126', 'AMELIA',  'Y17', 'DARK-DENIM',            '24', 179.95, '8052644627565' ]],
    columns=[ 'ITEM CODE', 'ITEM', 'COLOR', 'COLOR CODE', 'TG', 'PRICE', 'EAN' ])
```

Details:

- The first row does not contain any of `catp` keys in `ITEM CODE` column.
- The second row: `ITEM CODE` contains one of your codes (*2513*) but for `TG`
  column no tuple saved under `2513` key contains first element == *21*.
- The third row: `ITEM CODE` contains one of your codes (*2755*), `TG` == *24*
  and among tuples saved under `2755` there is one == *24*.

Then we have to define a couple of auxiliary functions:

```
def findContainedCodeAndVal(dct, str):
    for eachKey in dct.keys():
        if str.find(eachKey) >= 0:
            return (eachKey, dct[eachKey])
    else:
        return (None, None)
```

This function attempts to find in `dct` a key contained in `str`.
It returns a 2-tuple containing the key found and associated value from `dct`.

```
def find2ndElem(tuples, str):
    for tpl in tuples:
        if tpl[0] == str:
            return tpl[1]
    else:
        return ''
```

This function checks each tuple from `tuples` whether its first element
== `str` and returns the second element from this tuple.

And the last function to define is a function to be applied to each row
from your DataFrame. It returns the value to be saved in `SKU` column:

```
def fn(row):
    ind = row.name  # Read row index
    iCode = row['ITEM CODE']
    k, val = findContainedCodeAndVal(catp, iCode)
    codmarime = ''
    if k:
        tg = row.TG
        codmarime = find2ndElem(val, tg)
    if codmarime == '':
        codmarime = '???'
    return f'20/{iCode}/{ind}/{codmarime}'
```

Note that it uses your `catp` dictionary.

For demonstration purposes, I introduced in the returned value additional
slashes, separating adjacent parts. In the target version remove them.

And the last thing to do is to compute `SKU` column of your DataFrame,
applying `fn` function to each row of `df3` and saving the result under
`SKU` column:

```
df3['SKU'] = df3.apply(fn, axis=1)
```

When you print the DataFrame (containig my test data), `SKU` column will
contain:

```
20/1513452/0/???
20/2513452/1/???
20/2755126/2/002
```

Comment: Hello, I have a problem with your code, when the cells are empty:

----> 4     df3['SKU'] = df3.apply(fn, axis=1)
AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'find'", 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: It seems that the error occurs in *if str.find(eachKey) >= 0:* because *str* is either *NaN* or *None* (check which case it is).
To avoid this error, before *for eachKey in dct.keys():* you should check *str*.
If it is empty (*NaN* or *None*), then the function should return *(None, None)*. Other solution is to replace all *None* / *NaN* values with an empty string (*fillna()*).
If some value has been provided, the rest of this function should be executed. Other solution is to replace *None* values with an empty string (*fillna()*).

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to understand the question properly but just correcting the errors I see in your code:

`if catp.key() in df3['ITEM CODE'][i] and catp.value()[0] in df3['TG'][i]:`

This is incorrect.

I am taking a different approach should work if I understand the end-goal

```
for key in catp.keys():
     xdf = df3.loc[(df3['SKU'].astype(str).contains(key)) & (df3['SKU'].astype(str).contains(catp[key][0])]
     if len(xdf)>0:
         for i, row in xdf.iterrows():
                codmarime = catp[key][1]
                df3.at[i,'SKU'] = '20'+row['ITEM CODE'][i]+[i]+codmarime
```